# Why is for loop printing unexpected results?

Tags: java, for-loop, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I am scanning a black and white photo that is 100x100 pixels, trying to print every x and y coordinate (pixel by pixel) based on it being black or white. As the print statement is running, I can see the expected result in the console, but once it finishes, it begins producing a value of 0 for every outcome value and only prints north of x 95. Can you please explain how to fix this?

```
public class BW
{

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {    

BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(new File("maze.jpg"));
int red;

int[][] outcome = new int[original.getHeight()][original.getWidth()];
for(int i=0; i<original.getHeight(); i++)
{
for(int j=0; j<original.getWidth(); j++)
  {
red = new Color(original.getRGB(i, j)).getRed();

int pixel = 0;
if(red > 1)
{
outcome[i][j] = 255;
System.out.println("x: " + i + " y: " + j + " value: " + outcome[i][j]);
} else {
   outcome[i][j] = 0;
   System.out.println("x: " + i + " y: " + j + " value: " + outcome[i][j]);
} 
}
}

   } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
} 
}
```

The terminal output is below (it continues until an x of 99 and y if 99, with the y incrementing by 1, and the x switching from 98 to 99 halfway through-

[image: Output]

This is a screenshot I took while it was still running, where you can see it was calculating correctly. Once completed, it turns into the image above.

[image: While running]

Comment: what do you mean by "north of x 95"?

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` to `catch` block and see if it print anything.

Comment: @LuCio it does not matter as the array  is is a square

Comment: @TheScientificMethod You're right. OP says: 100 x 100 (removed my comment therefore)

Comment: i could not see where you are using the variable `pixel`?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod  Although it doesn't matter in this case it is still not properly initialized as it changed the dimensions. It is at least confusing,

Comment: I edited the original post so you can now see what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(int i=0; i<original.getWidth(); i++)
{
for(int j=0; j<original.getHeight(); j++)
{
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i<original.getHeight(); i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<original.getWidth(); j++)
   {
```

Comment: it does not matter as it is is a square.